# Angular 2 Is there a way to get access to the component logic or element style value inside animation metadata

Tags: angular, css-animations, angularjs-animation, angular2-animation

Basically what i need to know is is there a way to calculate the height of the component that is dynamically created from the recursive tree.
So obviously i cannot use tree inside my metadata declarations but i can calculate it height inside the *ngStyle directory like this

```
<my-directory [directory]='childDirectory' *ngStyle={'max-height:calcMaxHeight(childDirectory)><my-directory>
```

So let`s say my animations state is going to change the max height from one calculated by *ngStyle directive to 0, to create the slideUp effect.
But is there a way to access the value, previously calculated, inside animations metadata.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use the '*' to access the element dimensional properties.
[Here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html#!#automatic-property-calculation) is the article that explains it.